# No content in the websited after publishing the project from VS2013 to Azure host

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, host

Recently I follow the instructions from the Youtube tutorial to publish my asp.net web form application to the Azure host. I download the publish file and everything runs fine,  but at the last step in the preview option, it says there is no database selected. (Sorry I can't post images it says I need 10 reputations...)

And I continue to publish and it succeed! However, there is no content in the website! 
I am totally confused where is wrong with my operations.
Can anybody tell me how to publish a asp.net web form application(not in MVC) application to the Azure?
Thanks!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWSli4LGDa4 Here is the video that I followed.

Comment: can you post the video url that you followed ? or tell me how do you published the project (by publish profile maybe?)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWSli4LGDa4   This is the video that I followed. thanks!